# How NOT to generate timestamp in .obj/.exe/.a file?

Tags: timestamp

When I use visual.net to build my code, a timestamp will be generated in the .exe file. If I build twice, the exe files will have different timestamps, which will cause the them a little bit different.

Are there any way to let the compiler not to generate the timestamp so that the exe file built from the same code in different time will be same totally?

I have the same question when I use gcc, the .o and .a files have timestamp also.

thanks.

Backgroud: Our customer let us provide the source code files, they will compare the executable files built by themselves with we provided. Timestamp will cause the executable files a little bit different and make the zip file totally different. This will let our customer think the code files we provided is not the correct version of the executbale file we provied before.

Comment: Tell your customer to not be stupid...

Comment: It's hard to say that... In fact, they need the code so that they can maintaince the software if our company burst up.

Comment: Well then they can compile it on their own (they are doing that anyway if they compare it with your binaries) - or use your binaries and trust you not to have done anything bad.